# Umbraco unpublished Content fallback?

Tags: umbraco

We have an issue relating to “Unpublished Content” on our Umbraco (7.154) site:

****Our setup****

We have one Umbraco installation (7.154) which hosts multiple sites: each site appears as a "level 1" node, with its content/pages as "child nodes" appearing underneath.

Each site has a “Domain” set under “Culture and Hostnames” (New account here, can't display images directly):

[Site A - Node Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXI9S.png)

[Site B - Node Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLdAP.png)

*Under each Site, there is a “*Forgotten Password*” node with a similar Path (relative to its site root):*

•   Site A: “Home/Forgotten Password” (**unpublished** node).

•   Site B: “Home-****/Forgotten Password” (**published** node).

**The Issue**

On site A, when any hyperlink pointing to the “Forgotten Password” (relative path) is followed it resolves instead to the **SiteB** “Forgotten Password” node.

My understanding is that Umbraco URLs are resolved by a NodeID reference in the Umbraco DB: so these nodes should be unique despite having the "same" name.

Could this behaviour be Umbraco searching (by Node Name) for a "fallback" that is published?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure that it is actually resolving with the other node? Try outputting in the template the CurrentPage Id, because there's another mechanism that before resolving to a 404 error searches for a template with the same name (maybe in your case ForgottenPassword)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

They should as you mention be unique.  THings I suggest you try:

1. You could try clearing the cache.  This could be corrupted somehow.  In the backend, settings, examine, clear the indexes for external
2. Check your code, maybe it's a typo or something.
3. Are you using route-hijacking in our controller.  If so if you hit a break point, what ID is being passed into it from Umbraco.

Comment: Hello.

1. Clearing the cache and examine indexes: I'll try that. 
2. Can't see any typos in the code, worth checking though.
3. I will check for route hijacking, this could be the culprit.

On another note: when first learning Umbraco, I read almost all of your tutorials. Really helpful and I'd like to thank you for your effort!